# convert a asynchronous javascript code to synchronous code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have this `JavaScript` code in which I am making an `asynchronous` call to a function:

```
const configDefault = {
  Bot: {
    // initial sessionAttributes
    text: 'The state is not set',
  },
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  myIP();
});

function myIP() {
  $.getJSON("//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?", function(data) {

    myCallback(data.region_name); 
  });
}

function myCallback(State) {

   if(State == 'New York'){
   configDefault.Bot.text = 'State is New York';

   console.log(configDefault.Bot.text);
   }
   else {
   configDefault.Bot.text = 'State is different than New York';

   console.log(configDefault.Bot.text);

   }

};
```

The above `text` variable is called from a `vue.js` file with following syntax:

```
initMessageList(context) {
      context.commit('pushMessage', {
        type: 'text',
        text: context.state.config.Bot.text,
      });
    }
```

The `text` variable in `configDefault` is the message that comes on screen when this `javascript` page is loaded. Now the issue that I am facing is that since I am using an `asynchronous` call so it is causing timing issue and as such on screen I still see the original content in `text` - `The state is not set`  even though on console I can see `text` value as either `State is New York` or `State is different than New York`.

Now to resolve this issue I want to run the same code as synchronous so that this timing issue can be removed (In my understanding it should?). I am not at all familiar with JavaScript(I started using it just few days back and still learning) so I am not able to convert this into a synchronous version. Can anyone provide how can I implement the above in a synchronous version?

**Note:** My update code above is based on the following javascript/vue.js project at [this link](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/tree/master/lex-web-ui). I added the above code to [this file](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/lex-web-ui/src/config/index.js) in the mentioned project above(the `initialText` in the file is `text` in my code).

Comment: You should not make it synchronous.  You should have a "loading" message that gets replaced. So when you change the variable trigger an event that updates the DOM with the new value.

Comment: @epascarello since I don't know much of javascript can you explain it through an example?

Comment: JavaScript is built to be asynchronous. Programmers coming from other environments may find it difficult sometimes, but need to learn how to use asynchronous calls effectively. The way you're doing it in your question is correct, but if you're not seeing the result, then there must be something wrong in the rest of your code. Post all relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: @RacilHilan the code is working correctly and I can see the updated `text` value coming in the console but I think because of asynchronous call by the time the `text` filed is updated the original `text` value gets displayed

Comment: I understand that and you stated it clearly in your question. My point was that we need to see the rest of your code to help you. Obviously the order of displaying the original text and the result of the Ajax call is incorrect, but we cannot see that from the code you posted. We need to see the code that displays the original text, so we can help you put it in the correct order before the result of the Ajax call. That's all.

Comment: @RacilHilan I added some more info to my post above. My code is based on the project at this link - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/tree/master/lex-web-ui and my code is added to the file at   https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui/blob/master/lex-web-ui/src/config/index.js (`text` in my code is `initialText` in above code file)

Comment: OK, that's a library and it takes time to learn how to use it, so I cannot help you here with my limited time (perhaps somebody else can). I recommend you to read the library docs and learn how to use it. I suspect that the problem is caused by calling your `myIP` function inside `$(document).ready(function() {});` which is called after the page is loaded, but not necessarily after the library objects are initialized.

Comment: @RacilHilan I also suspect that the modification to `text` is done after the `text` has already been pushed to the message list to be displayed. The document does not mention anything specific to that.

Comment: Yes. That's what you need to figure out, not how to change it to synchronous. I recommend that you edit your question and add the explanation from our comments so people don't have to read them all, then remove the asynchronous tag and add a tag for the library that you're using. This way you increase the chance that somebody familiar with that library may see your question and help you.